# menuconfig and xconfig don't work!

Tags: 16.04, kernel, compiling, qt, configure

when I try to use `make menuconfig` I get this:

```
scripts/kconfig/mconf Kconfig init/Kconfig:1301: can't open file
"usr/Kconfig" scripts/kconfig/Makefile:24: recipe for target
'menuconfig' failed make[1]: *** [menuconfig] Error 1 Makefile:541:
recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

with `make xconfig` :

```
 CHECK   qt
* Unable to find the QT4 tool qmake. Trying to use QT3
*
* Unable to find any QT installation. Please make sure that
* the QT4 or QT3 development package is correctly installed and
* either qmake can be found or install pkg-config or set
* the QTDIR environment variable to the correct location.
* make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by 'scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop. Makefile:541: recipe for target 'xconfig' failed make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

PS: `libncurses5-dev` `libncursesw5-dev` and `qt` are already installed

How to solve this?

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version.

Comment: @N0rbert   ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hint from `apt-get install linux-source` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-source
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-source-4.4.0
Suggested packages:                                        #<--  suggestion 
  libncurses-dev | ncurses-dev kernel-package libqt3-dev   #<--  is here    
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-source linux-source-4.4.0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The `libqt3-dev` is not available, but you can install Qt4 one.

So you should install three packages and build tools:

```
sudo apt install ncurses-dev kernel-package qt4-dev-tools pkg-config build-essential
```

Then you will be able to run `make menuconfig` and `make xconfig`.

Comment: thank you.. but ..it's still the same msg when i try menuconfig..xconfig returns this new error                                                                     
scripts/kconfig/qconf Kconfig
init/Kconfig:1301: can't open file "usr/Kconfig"
scripts/kconfig/Makefile:18: recipe for target 'xconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [xconfig] Error 1
Makefile:541: recipe for target 'xconfig' failed
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2

Comment: I dunno the problem with usr/Kconfig !!

Comment: it worked! thank youuu @N0rbert  ... well..the last err was because of the kernel.. i reinstalled it ..and thank for ur answer ..i can use xconfig now